# Trying to add a hyperlink to a web based table generator

Tags: html

Sorry but I really have no experience in web-developing.  I am trying to make a web site for my boys soccer team and have been working with the godaddy website builder system.  The issue I have is I build a table using a web based table building site, tablesgenerator.com, and built the table with my player roster.  Now what I am trying to do is make each players name a hyperlink to there own page so I can customize it for each.  Please help because I have tried so many things.  I will add some of the code from the table to show you what I am working with.

```
    <th class="tg-n19i">NUMBER</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">NAME</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">POSITION</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">GRADE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-43qd">5</td>
    <td class="tg-43qd">Osvaldo Araujo</td>
    <td class="tg-43qd">Mid/Def</td>
    <td class="tg-43qd">12</td>
```

As you can see the name is the second line and I just need to find a way to link it.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, is your requirement to add a link to the html that was created by the generator? Isn't it?

Comment: In addition to @Shaffanhoon's answer, check the [W3School about anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) for hyperlinking

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a page for each of the players you could make their name a link like this:

```
    <th class="tg-n19i">NUMBER</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">NAME</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">POSITION</th>
    <th class="tg-3wsf">GRADE</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-43qd">5</td>
    <td class="tg-43qd"><a href="page url">Osvaldo Araujo</a></td>
    <td class="tg-43qd">Mid/Def</td>
    <td class="tg-43qd">12</td>
```

You would just need to change the "page url" bit for each team member's respective page.

Comment: So I did this and it works except you cant see the players name.  I have a white background so I am guessing the text is white for the link instead of black.  Do you know how I can make sure it stays black?